# Как передать координаты для захвата видео с X-сервера интерактивно в ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, xorg

Позаимствовал команду [отсюда](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117623)

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s $(slop --noopengl --format "%w"x"%h") -r 60 -i :0.0 -qscale 0 -vcodec huffyuv $(date +"%d.%m.%Y_%H:%M:%S").avi
```

но это работает только если нет отступов при записи, то есть проще говоря записывается полностью весь экран. Смещение позиции на экране например, указав "-s 800x600 -i :0.0+200,100" можно организовать запись блока 800x600 со смещением 200x100 относительно верхнего левого угла экрана.

Примерно так:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 800x600 -r 60 -i :0.0+200,100 -qscale 0 -vcodec huffyuv $(date +"%d.%m.%Y_%H:%M:%S").avi
```

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы можно было интерактивно мышью выделять с помощью того же slop и потом эти координаты передавать в ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставим разделитель массива `+`

```
IFS="+"
```

Читаем вывод slop как массив

```
read -ra SR <<< `slop`
```

Теперь переменную с пробелами можно читать по индексам

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s ${SR[0]} -r 60 -i :0.0+${SR[1]},${SR[2]} ....
```

Можно с IFS по умолчанию (`IFS=' '`) если указать формат через пробел

Comment: Вы написали что поставить разделитель массива, а как его нужно установить?

Comment: `IFS="+"` - вот же

Comment: это я понял, но как его потом использовать?

Comment: `read -ra SR <<< ` чтоб считать массив

Comment: read: bad option: -a

Comment: какая у вас ос?

Comment: запусти в bash или в zsh. в sh или ash может и нет такой опции

Comment: у меня zsh (оно не работает в zsh)
ОС ArchLinux

Comment: запускай под bash) на zsh оказывается другой веселый способ

Comment: Всё заработало. А я ломаю голову, думаю что то не так делаю, а оно оказывается что bash и zsh разные. Я всё таки думал что у zsh есть какая то обратная совместимость с bash. Спасибо Вам огромное :)